# Unique elements in collections in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there an easy way to ensure that elements in a collection in Neo4j/Cypher are unique? Something like making the collection into a hashset?

Comment: When you say 'collection', do you mean the results of a query, or the as a property on nodes/relationships?

Comment: I mean as a property on nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity(Node/Relationship) properties do not have a concept of `Set`, they have key/values, and an allowed value is a primitive/String array.

If you want `Set` like features, it will be up to your application that is inserting the data to enforce this uniqueness.

Cypher doesn't have any functionality for this either.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to do this with Cypher.

For example, if you just want to add an item to the property only if it does not exist you can do so in a couple of ways.

This example filters the query and is useful if the collection modification is the only property being modified:

```
START n=node({id}) WHERE NONE(x IN n.cols WHERE x = {val}) SET n.cols = n.cols + {val} RETURN n;
```

This next example will end up always modifying the property, but would ensure uniqueness and would be a useful method if some other properties also need to be modified at the same time, however a side effect is that the order of the items will change:

```
START n=node({id})
WITH n, FILTER(x IN n.cols WHERE x <> {val}) as existingCols 
SET n.cols = existingCols + {val}
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. The only problem is that START clause is deprecated and removed in Cypher 3.2 as per https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/start/. You need to use MATCH instead; something like this: MATCH (n:node {uid: "1234"}) WHERE NONE(x IN n.arr WHERE x = "value") SET n.arr = n.arr + "value" RETURN n;

Answer (score -1):

In cypher, you can work with collections ([1](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/syntax-collections.html), [2](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-collection.html)) and you can ensure uniqueness by using the `DISTINCT` [modifier](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-distinct), as in

```
...
MATCH (fred)-[:LIKES]->(fruit)<-[:LIKES]-(fruit_friend)
WITH fred, COLLECT(DISTINCT(fruit_friend)) as unique_fruit_friends
...
```